# Compare each columns of two data frames and output only diff columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames here:
df1 is here

```
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|     OrgId|ItemId|segmentId|Sequence|Action|
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|4295877341|   136|        9|       1|  I|!||
|4295877342|   111|        4|       2|  I|!||
|4295877343|   138|        2|       1|  I|!||
|4295877344|   141|        4|       1|  I|!||
|4295877345|   143|        2|       1|  I|!||
|4295877346|   145|       14|       1|  d|!||
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
```

df2 is here:

```
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|     OrgId|ItemId|segmentId|Sequence|Action|
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|4295877341|   136|        4|       1|  I|!||
|4295877342|   136|        4|       1|  I|!||
|4295877343|   900|        2|       1|  K|!||
|4295877344|   141|        4|       1|  D|!||
|4295877345|   111|        2|       1|  I|!||
|4295877346|   145|       14|       1|  I|!||
|4295877347|   145|       14|       1|  I|!||
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
```

What i need is only all columns value which is present if df1 not in df2 .
Like below ...

```
4295877341|^|segmentId=9,segmentId=4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877342|^|ItemId=111,ItemId=136|^|Sequence=2,Sequence=1|^|I|!|
```

And so on for each row ...

Here OrgId is my primary key for both the dataframe .

So basically for each OrgId i need to collect both versions ,just column changed value .

Here what i have tried so far .

```
val columns = df1.schema.fields.map(_.name)
val selectiveDifferences = columns.map(col => 
df1.select(col).except(df2.select(col)))
selectiveDifferences.map(diff => {if(diff.count > 0) diff.show})
```

But it gives me the Except output only with one column at a time .

Regards,
Sudarshan

Comment: It doesn't seem to produce the expected output either - what if you have value X for column Y for two different `OrgId`s in the two dataframes - these won't show up (because `except` would remove X) but they appeared for different `OrgId`s.

Comment: @TzachZohar sorry i have edited my question ...I think i have to figure out some other way ...

Comment: And what is the _schema_ of the expected result? Rows in a DataFrame must all have the same structure, you can't have one row with N columns and another with N+1 columns. Do you want to still have separate column similar to input, with `null`s where there was no diff? Or do you want to "merge" all column into one array/map column? Please define the EXACT structure of the desired output.

Comment: @TzachZohar if there is change in column then it should appear if there is no change then it should be hidden ...Merging all columns into one arrry/map will also be fine ...

Comment: Please be precise - what is the _schema_ of the expected result? What are the columns and the column types? Once again, a column can't "appear" for one record and not appear for the other - the entire DataFrame must have the same schema.

Comment: @TzachZohar This is what i needed i know its very difficult to get in required format ..But if null is allowed can we do that then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154844/discussion-between-tzach-zohar-and-sudarshan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not define the desired structure for the output, so I'll assume keeping the columns separate, with each column containing an *array* of the differing values or `null` if they match would suffice:

```
// list of columns to compare
val cols = df1.columns.filter(_ != "OrgId").toList

// function to create an expression that results in null for similar values,
// and with a two-item array with the differing values otherwise
def mapDiffs(name: String) = when($"l.$name" === $"r.$name", null)
  .otherwise(array($"l.$name", $"r.$name"))
  .as(name)

// joining the two DFs on OrgId
val result = df1.as("l")
  .join(df2.as("r"), "OrgId")
  .select($"OrgId" :: cols.map(mapDiffs): _*)

result.show()
// +----------+----------+---------+--------+------------+
// |     OrgId|    ItemId|segmentId|Sequence|      Action|
// +----------+----------+---------+--------+------------+
// |4295877341|      null|   [9, 4]|    null|        null|
// |4295877342|[111, 136]|     null|  [2, 1]|        null|
// |4295877343|[138, 900]|     null|    null|[I|!|, K|!|]|
// |4295877344|      null|     null|    null|[I|!|, D|!|]|
// |4295877345|[143, 111]|     null|    null|        null|
// |4295877346|      null|     null|    null|[d|!|, I|!|]|
// +----------+----------+---------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: This is what i need but can we not replace null with some blank space?

Comment: Not really - because a column must have a single type, and these columns are of type `Array[Int]` or `Array[String]` - a "blank space" isn't an array. More importantly - you should make sure you know whether (and why) a blank space would be better - I don't see how it would be usable at all.

Comment: Can we use except function first and then join the first data frame with except generated dataframe?

val cols = DF1.columns.filter(_ != "emp_id").toList
val DF3 = DF1.except(DF2)
def mapDiffs(name: String) = when($"l.$name" === $"r.$name", null ).otherwise(array($"l.$name", $"r.$name")).as(name)
val result = DF2.as("l").join(DF3.as("r"), "emp_id").select($"emp_id" :: cols.map(mapDiffs): _*)

So that we do not see the rows that there is no change in it and in addition to that our join would be less expensive